# GLMMadaptive for semi-continuous data

Tags: r

I am dealing with a very hard-to-work data set: fish larval density. It is a semicontinuous data, with 90% of zeros and a right-skewed distribution, with few very huge values. I would like, for example, to make some predictions about enviromental features and and larval density. I am trying to use a two part model (**GLMMadaptive** for semicontinuous data), `family = hurdle.lognormal()`.

But the command *summary* does not work with models fitted with `mixed_model()`, `family = hurdle.lognormal()`. So, I don't know how to get  standard errors, p-values and confidence intervals for my predictors.

Another question is related to Goodness of Fit for the residuals. How can I look for it?

Also, I tried to fit a null model, without fixed effects, looking for model significance, but I couldn't fix it, because it gives me the following message:

*Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : subscript out of bounds*

```
Nullmodel <- mixed_model(fixed = Dprochilodus ~ 1, random = ~ 1|periodo, data = OeL_final, family = hurdle.lognormal(), max_coef_value = 30) 

mymodel <- mixed_model(fixed = Dprochilodus ~ ponto+Dif_his.y+temp,  random = ~ 1 | periodo, data = OeL_final, family = hurdle.lognormal(), n_phis = 1,      zi_fixed = ~ ponto, max_coef_value = 30)
```

The results of my model are:

```
Call: mixed_model(fixed = logDprochilodus ~ ponto + Dif_his.y + temp, 
    random = ~1 | periodo, data = OeL_final, family = hurdle.lognormal(), 
    zi_fixed = ~ponto, n_phis = 1, max_coef_value = 30)


Model:  family: hurdle log-normal  link: identity 

Random effects covariance matrix:
                StdDev (Intercept) 0.05366623

Fixed effects:   (Intercept)       pontoIR      pontoITA      pontoJEQ pontoTB     Dif_his.y          temp 
 3.781147e-01 -1.161167e-09  3.660306e-01 -1.273341e+00 -5.834588e-01  1.374241e+00 -4.010771e-02 

Zero-part coefficients: (Intercept)     pontoIR    pontoITA    pontoJEQ     pontoTB 
  1.4522523  21.3761790   3.3013379   1.1504374   0.2031707 

Residual std. dev.:
 1.240212 

log-Lik: -216.3266
```

Have some one worked with this kind of model?? I really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

The `summary()` method should work with `family = hurdle.lognormal()`. For example, you can call `summary()` in the example posted [here](https://drizopoulos.github.io/GLMMadaptive/articles/ZeroInflated_and_TwoPart_Models.html#two-part-mixed-effects-model-for-semi-continuous-data).

To check the goodness-of-fit you could use the simulated scale residuals provided from the **DHARMa** package; for an example check [here](https://drizopoulos.github.io/GLMMadaptive/articles/Goodness_of_Fit.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in Rstudio console you may need to print(summary())